# Socket closed to GCM connection server using XMPP

Tags: android, sockets, erlang, google-cloud-messaging

I have a simple app server written in Erlang that uses XMPP to send downstream messages. Client apps are expected to be Android devices. My Erlang module implements `gen_server` behavior; on `init` it connects to GCM Connection Server (CCS) using XMPP,
and it has one exported function to send downstream messages.

The problem is SSL socket gets closed when I try to send a message. If I don't send any messages the socket is being closed in 20 seconds.

Authentication is successfully done, I do receive `<success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>` response. Upon sending a message there is no ACK messages, the socket closes immediately.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/bazi/gcm-xmpp). It is an Erlang project using `rebar3`.

What do I missing here? Why is my socket connection gets closed?

Comment: I am not sure if it's OK to open the socket in the init function. Usually there is a limited amount of time for the supervisor to start all the `gen_servers`. Have a look how they do that in this example: https://github.com/erlware/Erlang-and-OTP-in-Action-Source/blob/master/chapter_11/gen_web_server/src/gws_server.erl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved by sending additional stanzas after authentication. Check out the code whose link is mentioned above in the question to see what stanzas shall be interchanged in order to be able to send notifications.

[GCM CCS docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#format) lack this info and thus the problem arose.